# Feeling sarcastic and rude when I write "please" (in emails)

Tags: word-choice, politeness, formal-language

Maybe I've watched too much television where everyone is sarcastic and upset about each other, but I feel like when I say *please* to ask for something, as in "*Could you please change that ?*", or "*Please try doing this instead.*", I'm doing the opposite of being polite.

I can't help but read it in a judgemental, condescending voice, does it feel the same for a native ?

For now it feels better without the *please* : "*Could you change that ?*" "*Try doing that instead*". What should I say ?

Comment: In this context, sarcasm is usually indicated by the way in which the words are accented, not by the inclusion of the word *please*. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: In speaking, intonation is everything.  In writing, it is difficult to know what voice the reader may be using...

Comment: Related: [How much more polite does the word please make a request?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52105/)

Comment: Be aware that sarcasm combined with understatement or nominally polite expressions can differ greatly between British English & American English...

Comment: @JohnFeltz How so ?

Comment: I don't see anything sarcastic about using *please*.  In my business communications, we use it all the time, e.g. "Please change the frobnitzer setting to 'high'."

Comment: @Teleporting Goat - there are entire books written on the subject.  In general, American English is more straightforward and literal.  "I think we should consider some other alternatives" means exactly that in AmE, but can mean "Your idea is terrible" in BrE.

Comment: @JohnFeltz In other words, the British are more skilled in passive aggression than we colonials...

Comment: Use of the conditionals _would you_ or _could you_ increases the likelihood that the request will be interpreted as expressing impatience. Adding _please_ as in _Would you please_ makes such an interpretation a near certainty. The effect is only slightly reduced by substituting _could_ for _would._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hear you.  I generally avoid *please* in writing, precisely because of ambiguities that could lead someone to take things the wrong way.  I agree with you that those sentences sound a bit more polite without it.

A pretty surefire way to make your requests sound polite is to phrase them as a request.  "Try doing that instead" may sound better as, "Can you try doing that instead?"  "Could/Can you change that?" sounds fine.

When you do this, the *please* is no longer really necessary.  And I think when you add it in, it sounds a little overly-polite, which could lead some people to  interpret your politeness sarcastically.  Or it can sound impatient.

That's not to say *please* is never used to be polite, but making it sound sincere depends a lot on intonation and stress, which are absent in writing.

Comment: If the interlocutor feels that the demand is comminatory or if he strongly disagrees with it, the word "please" (quite insincere in this case) would make the request more offensive.

Answer (score 1):

In my - maybe old-fashioned - world, using 'please' still is a way of being polite.
I have to deal with U.S. technicians, clerks, attorneys, ... and all of them use it for that purpose.
In normal conversation I would consider it rude to omit 'please'. Even worse: A request ends with an exclamation mark.
Of course, if you ask for the third time within one week without getting any response, a more or less sarcastic 'please' plus exclamation mark could be justified.